# Append new keys to a JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, append

I have this JSON array that Zabbix retrieves as a string and each object has the keys "*startTime*" and "*endTime*" which are date-time strings in the format of "**DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss**".

Using Javascript, I'm trying to add a new key to each object in the array.
The new key is called "***execTime***" and it should have a value equal to the difference between "*endTime*" and "*startTime*" in seconds.

**Input JSON sample:**

```
[
    {
    "endTime": "02-02-2024 10:10:20",
    "startTime": "02-02-2024 10:10:10",
    },
    {
    (...)
    }
]
```

**Expected output JSON:**

```
[
    {
    "endTime": "02-02-2024 10:10:20",
    "startTime": "02-02-2024 10:10:10",
    "execTime": 10
    },
    {
    (...)
    }
]
```

For that, I was trying to use the following script.

```
function (value) {
    const jsonValue = JSON.parse(value);

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonValue.length; i++) {
      const startDate = new Date(jsonValue[i].startTime);
      const endDate = new Date(jsonValue[i].endTime);

      const execTime = ( endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime() ) / 1000;
      if ( execTime < 0 ) { var execTime = 0; }
      jsonValue[i].execTime = execTime;
    };

    return jsonValue;
}
```

The problem is that the return value is this:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], (...)
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What were you expecting the return value to be?  Both look like a list of objects to me.  What do you get when you view the input to this function in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return JSON.stringify(jsonValue);

// Convert the result back to a JSON-formatted string

Comment: Thank you. The returning value is now a JSON string, but now the output has no "execTime" keys. It is the same as the input.

Comment: I had a few errors in my For loop. That's why I had the returned value without the execTime. Now it is fixed and works as expected. Thanks for your feedback.